# Video sequence editor preview video is full screen

Tags: video-sequence-editor

The preview panel in video editing is taking up the whole area of blender. I don't know how to get out of it. There are no buttons or menus anywhere.

I tried:

```
Alt-F10     - Toggles maximize/restore window.
Ctrl-Up     - Nothing
Ctrl-Down   - Nothing
Shift-Space - Nothing
Alt-F11     - Toggles real full-screen (no window)/window
```

Comment: In the video sequence editor I clicked on View (of the preview pane) and clicked Toggle Fullscreen Area Alt-F10. If I press Alt-F10 it just maximizes the window, but if I click on the Toggle it takes over the whole work-space.

Comment: Did you restart? In all files you open? You can create a new file and append everything. Do your keyboard keys register correct? Can you split the window?

Comment: could it be that you have joined all panels into one? If so, you could split back the only one  into multiple, using the little corner handles, see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html#splitting-and-joining If nothing works, save the file (ctrl-s or ctrl-w). then close blender completely, reopen it and load the saved file _without_ the "load ui" flag...

Comment: I restarted nothing changed. Only this file is saved like this. I appended everything in a new file but I don't have what I made. It was just video editing. No 3d models. I can't split the window. There are no handles in the corners. Loading the file with the "load ui" unchecked worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-s` or `Ctrl-w` to save current progress.

Open the file by **un-checking** the `Load UI` parameter.